# If $n\in\Bbb N$, then gcd($8n+1, 7n+1)$ =

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If  $n\in\Bbb N$, then gcd($8n+1, 7n+1)$ =

How to do these type of questions?

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that $\gcd(8n+1,7n+1)=d$. Then $d\mid 8n+1$ and $d\mid 7n+1$, so $d\mid n=(8n+1)-(7n+1)$. Then we have $d\mid 1=(7n+1)-7n$. Therefore we must have $d=1$.

The general strategy is to take linear combinations of things you know are divisible by $d$.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty easy just using: 
$8(7n+1)-7(8n+1)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Or two steps of Euclid's algorithm. The first step yields n, the second step yields 1.